# Page Numbering on List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I would like to show the page numbering on the footer for each page on List Of Figure.
It is just showing on the first page of the List of figures.
The LaTex code is below:

```
\renewcommand\listoffigures{%
    \coppe@hasLof
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listfigurename}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
              {\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

Comment: Please always provide a full but minimal example and not sniplets like this. We cannot test code like this without having to add code, code that will probably be different from yours. For example where does `\coppe@hasLof` come from? Never seen that before.

Comment: you have not shown any code related to the page style so hard to say what to change

Comment: Make sure that  `\frontmatter ` activated before `\listoffigures`.  (without %)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I can expand Bruno's question, since it looks like I have the same problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\input{./structure.tex}

\onehalfspacing
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\tocloftpagestyle{plain}
\begin{document}

\input{./title.tex}

\pagestyle{empty}
\input{./Chapters/thanks}

\cleardoublepage


\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\input{./Chapters/abstract}

\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents


\cleardoublepage


\protect \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}

\listoffigures




\cleardoublepage
\protect \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables



\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\input{./Chapters/1_intro.tex}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{\uppercase{Literatura}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{Literatura}}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat-GFRI}
%\bibliographystyle{ksfh_nat}
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
```

"structure.tex" contains all the packages needed for compilation. I can add it if neccesary.

What happends with the code, it adds page numbering to table of contents, list of figures and list of tables. The list of figures starts with "ii" and the list of tables starts with "iv" as it should be, but there is no "iii" on the second page of list of figures.

[image]